# How to Download Images through URL to internal memory?

Tags: android, firebase-storage

I want to Download my images which i have uploaded to Firebase. I Got the URL and was able to load them Directly to my desired ImageView. But I want to download them to my **desired path** in **internal Storage**.

I Have Used Picasso But its not working for me as i am getting the error attached below when Using **( new Target() )** This is the Error i got using Picasso with  Target

[image]

And the Code For Picasso is Below

```
Picasso.get()
                .load(downloadUrl)
                .into(new Target() {
                          @Override
                          public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                              try {

                                  String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
                                  File myDir = new File(root + "/yourDirectory");

                                  if (!myDir.exists()) {
                                      myDir.mkdirs();
                                  }

                                  String name = new Date().toString() + ".jpg";
                                  myDir = new File(myDir, name);
                                  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(myDir);
                                  bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);

                                  out.flush();
                                  out.close();
                              } catch(Exception e){
                                  // some action
                              }
                          }

                          @Override
                          public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

                          //Some Action;
                          }

                          @Override
                          public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
                            //Some Action;
                          }
                      }
                );
```

I have Searched in the Documentation But that Didn't Work. Please Let me Know As soon as possible. If someone have the Right Answer. Thanks in Advance

Comment: You should implement the required methods used by the `Target` class. Right click and select implement methods(or anything like that if mentioned :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**first**: implement `Taget` class methods to clear the error

**second**:your code throws this `exception java.io.FileNotFoundException`
because the default format of `Date` object is like that `Mon Jan 21 12:10:23 GMT+02:00 2019`
and you can't create file with name contains **:** colon

**third:** check if you add `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` Permission in `androidManiefest.xml` and you need to use runtime permission in marshmallow

Comment: I have implemented Target class

Comment: i have modified the date already and also added the permissions. But still i am having the same issue . As mentioned in the screen shot above.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** To remove error, you have to implement methods of Target class.

For Download Image, You can find solution from the link

https://www.codexpedia.com/android/android-download-and-save-image-through-picasso/

> ```java
> Picasso.with(this).load(anImageUrl).into(picassoImageTarget(getApplicationContext(), "imageDir", "my_image.jpeg"));
> ```

**method**

> ```java
> private Target picassoImageTarget(Context context, final String
> imageDir, final String imageName) {
>     Log.d("picassoImageTarget", " picassoImageTarget");
>     ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(context);
>     final File directory = cw.getDir(imageDir, Context.MODE_PRIVATE); // path to /data/data/yourapp/app_imageDir
>     return new Target() {
>         @Override
>         public void onBitmapLoaded(final Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
>             new Thread(new Runnable() {
>                 @Override
>                 public void run() {
>                     final File myImageFile = new File(directory, imageName); // Create image file
>                     FileOutputStream fos = null;
>                     try {
>                         fos = new FileOutputStream(myImageFile);
>                         bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
>                     } catch (IOException e) {
>                         e.printStackTrace();
>                     } finally {
>                         try {
>                             fos.close();
>                         } catch (IOException e) {
>                             e.printStackTrace();
>                         }
>                     }
>                    Log.i("image", "image saved to >>>" + myImageFile.getAbsolutePath());
>
>                 }
>             }).start();
>         }
>
>         @Override
>         public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
>         }
>         @Override
>         public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
>             if (placeHolderDrawable != null) {}
>         }
>     }; }
> ```